# nodeList gives only last item with onClick

Tags: javascript

I have a JSON file which gives me every country, and I place these within `<li>` tags.

I want to loop through this list, and put a click event on every `<li>`, which it does. But no matter what I click on, I always get the last item in the list returned to me. What am I missing?

I want the item I'm clicking returned.

```
function lists() {
    var items = document.querySelectorAll('#Countries>ul>li');
    for (i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {   
       var item = items[i];
       item.onclick = function() {
          console.log(item);
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: replace `var item = items[i];` with `let item = items[i];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its a scoping issue, `var` is function scope.

you can use `let` from es6 to declare the variable, or another way is to use `bind`.

```js
function lists() {
  var items = document.querySelectorAll('#Countries>ul>li');
  for (i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    var item = items[i];
    item.onclick = function() {
      console.log(this);
    }.bind(item);
  }
}
lists();
```

```html
<div id="Countries">
  <ul>
    <li>country1</li>
    <li>country2</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass the `item` in the `onclick` function as a parameter. This is because the function inside the for loop will consider only the last item.

```
function lists() {
    var items = document.querySelectorAll('#Countries>ul>li');
    for (i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {   
       var item = items[i];
       item.onclick = function(item) {
          console.log(item);
       }
    }
}
```

You can also use let to isolate the scope:

```
function lists() {
    let items = document.querySelectorAll('#Countries>ul>li');
    for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {   
       let item = items[i];
       item.onclick = function() {
          console.log(item);
       }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Declare the variable with `let` in the for loop that will declare a block scope local variable. Try

```
for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
```